# Running loops or multi-line code on Heroku Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console, heroku

Heroku console doesn't run loops in my app (though they work on my local machine AND heroku permits individual actions to be taken).

```
@companies.each do |c|
SyntaxError: /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected $end
@companies.each do |c|
                      ^
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:140:in `eval'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:140:in `_eval'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:73:in `block in process_command'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
```

Do you know why these errors might be occurring?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

it's not an error - it's a feature of how Heroku let's you interact with your application via the `heroku console` command - whilst appearing like a full console it simply isn't. Each line is transmitted over http and evaluated when you press enter so you can't actually use multiline commands, this will work though;

```
User.all.each {|user| user.update_attributes(:active => true) }
```

if it can't be written on one line you'll need to use a rake task or such like

EDITED: To contain correct syntax

Comment: This actually didn't work for me on the Heroku console.  It still fails at `|user|` similar to how the OP failed at `|c|` and my syntax is the same as written in the answer.

Comment: You can also use semicolons ";" to write multiple lines of code on one physical line.

Comment: @mpoisot - how? Can you please give an example of this?

Comment: @sscirrus - write your multiline code in your favorite editor, then replace newlines with ';', and paste the result into the console. Example: `User.all.each do |user|; newname = user.name + "new"; puts newname; end`

Answer (score 6):

The proper syntax for this would be (at least for Ruby 1.9.2 on Heroku):

```
User.all.each {|user| user.update_attributes(:active => true)}
```

Using John's method didn't work for me (and I ran into this issue a 2nd time so it was time to write an answer that worked for others).

By the way, if you want multiple lines of code, you have to pass it all in as one line like this:

```
User.all.each {|user| user.some_attribute = true; user.some_other_attribute = false; user.save }
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but if you are using Rails you can also use the very helpful [rails runner](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) command

```
heroku run rails runner "
 User.find_each do |user| 
   user.update(active: true)
 end

 #Any other multiline logic
" -a my_app
```

I used [#find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) on the example because it's better for larger collections of objects.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I found so far to execute multi line code of arbitrary length in Heroku console is to wrap my code into a class with the executable code wrapped into a class method

```
class DoSomething
  def self.run
    puts "line1"
    puts "line2 .... etc"
  end
end
```

then paste this into the console and hit Enter

now your class is available to you and you can invoke the method you defined on it:

> DoSomething.run

so, this way there's no need to jump through the hoops and squeeze everything onto a single line